# Firebase Question - Uncaught TypeError: firebaseApp.firestore is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';


const firebaseConfig = {
  projectId: "projectId"
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { db, auth };
```

Comment: Have you checked that the `firebaseApp` is successfully initialized? You can do so quickly and easily with a `console.log`. If it is failing, then that would cause your error message.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your error, you need to add `import 'firebase/compat/firestore'` under your import statements. Also, check the documentation to [update imports to v9 compat](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat).

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';


const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { db, auth };
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to import Firestore SDK to use it. Try adding the following import below auth:

```
import "firebase/compat/firestore"
```